# Android, SQLite, Json, WooCommerce

Tags: android, json, sqlite, woocommerce

For my android app,I am fetching the data from woocommerce rest api.
What I want to do is apply filter for my app,for that, first I am getting the data from rest api and parsing those json datas.Before I am displaying those datas into my recycler view I am storing those datas into my DB.and then I get the data from DB and set the adapter for recycler view.Now when I click it'll filter the view by price range whatever I've given.Everything is working fine.
For my Main activity I am getting the data from products/categories api and displaying in recycler view.works fine.when I click one of the item it'll go to next activity where I am calling /products api and those datas are displays after storing into my db.till here works fine.
Now problem is whenever I go back and click on the different item,it is showing the same datas of products which was previously clicked.I don't know why?

Edit..
here is my code for item clicked in recylcer view adapter class.

```
> public void onClick(View view) {
>             int position = getAdapterPosition();
>             SubCategoryDataModel display = this.subCategory.get(position);
>             Intent intent = new Intent(context,ProductsActivity.class);
>             intent.putExtra("id",display.getId());
>             intent.putExtra("name",display.getName());
>             this.context.startActivity(intent);
> 
>         }
```

Product Activity

```
private String productsUrl;
private String url = "https://XXXXxxxxx.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_xxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
List<ProductsDataModel> productsDataList;
List<ProductsDataModel.ProductImage> imageList;
DataSource mDataSource;
List<ProductsDataModel> listFromDB;
ProductsAdapter adpter;

ImageButton listGrid;
Button sort,filter;
boolean isPressed = false;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    listGrid = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.list_grid);
    sort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);
    filter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter);

    filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayDataItems("15000");
        }
    });

    sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayDataItems(null);
        }
    });

    intent = new Intent(getIntent());
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    System.out.println("id clicked  " + id);
    productsUrl = url + "&category=" +id;



    new JsonTask().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mDataSource.close();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDataSource.open();
}


class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ProductsDataModel>> {


    @Override
    protected List<ProductsDataModel> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request  = new Request.Builder()
                .url(productsUrl)
                .build();
        productsDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            JSONArray jsonArray  = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
            Log.d("json array", "doInBackground: "  + jsonArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ProductsDataModel productDataModel = new ProductsDataModel();
                productDataModel.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                productDataModel.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                productDataModel.setPrice(jsonObject.getString("price"));
                productDataModel.setDesc(jsonObject.getString("description"));

                imageList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray imageArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");

                for ( int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++ ) {
                    JSONObject imageObject = imageArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    ProductsDataModel.ProductImage productImage = new ProductsDataModel.ProductImage();
                    productImage.setSrc(imageObject.getString("src"));
                    imageList.add(productImage);
                }
                productDataModel.setImagesList(imageList);
                productsDataList.add(productDataModel);
            }
            return productsDataList;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ProductsDataModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mDataSource = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
        mDataSource.open();
        mDataSource.seedDatabase(productsDataList);

        displayDataItems(null);


//            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter =  new ProductsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),productsDataList);
//            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
}

private void displayDataItems(String str) {
    listFromDB = mDataSource.getAllItems(str);
    adpter = new ProductsAdapter(this,listFromDB);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adpter);

}
}
```

ProductsDataModel

```
  private String id;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String desc;
    private List<ProductImage> imagesList;

public ProductsDataModel() {
}

public ProductsDataModel(String id, String name, String price, String desc, List<ProductImage> imagesList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imagesList = imagesList;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public List<ProductImage> getImagesList() {
    return imagesList;
}

public void setImagesList(List<ProductImage> imagesList) {
    this.imagesList = imagesList;
}

public static class ProductImage {
    private String src;

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

}

public ContentValues toValues() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ItemsTable.COLUMN_ID,id);
    values.put(ItemsTable.COLUMN_NAME,name);
    values.put(ItemsTable.COLUMN_PRICE,price);
    values.put(ItemsTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,desc);
    return values;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.price);
    dest.writeString(this.desc);
    dest.writeList(this.imagesList);
}

protected ProductsDataModel(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.price = in.readString();
    this.desc = in.readString();
    this.imagesList = new ArrayList<ProductImage>();
    in.readList(this.imagesList, ProductImage.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProductsDataModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ProductsDataModel>() {
    @Override
    public ProductsDataModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ProductsDataModel(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductsDataModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProductsDataModel[size];
    }
};
}
```

DataSource class.

```
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
SQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper;

public DataSource(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void open() {
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public ProductsDataModel createProducts(ProductsDataModel product){
    ContentValues values = product.toValues();
    mDatabase.insert(ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    return product;
}

public long getDataItemsCount(){
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDatabase,ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME);
}

// checking data is alrready inserted or not.

public void seedDatabase(List<ProductsDataModel> productsDataModelList){
    long numItems = getDataItemsCount();
    if ( numItems == 0 ){
        for (ProductsDataModel products : productsDataModelList ){
            try {
                createProducts(products);
            } catch (SQLiteException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<ProductsDataModel> getAllItems(String str){
    List<ProductsDataModel> productsData = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (str == null ) {
        cursor = mDatabase.query(ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME,ItemsTable.ALL_COLUMNS,
                null,null,null,null,ItemsTable.COLUMN_NAME);
    } else {
        String[] str1 = {str};
        cursor = mDatabase.query(ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME,ItemsTable.ALL_COLUMNS,
                ItemsTable.COLUMN_PRICE + ">?",str1,null,null,ItemsTable.COLUMN_NAME);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        ProductsDataModel products = new ProductsDataModel();
        products.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COLUMN_ID)));
        products.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COLUMN_NAME)));
        products.setDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
        products.setPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemsTable.COLUMN_PRICE)));
        productsData.add(products);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return productsData;
}
}
```

Comment: Share your code..what have you done so far..of item clicked..

Comment: I have added my code.@Meenal

Comment: you are calling finish when going back from Product Activity..